# MQTT-SN how to "UNREGISTER" a given topic when using wildcard?

Tags: mqtt, paho

I am using the paho library (in C language) for MQTT-SN implementation on a BC660K dev-kit.

So far, I am able to do any common stuff like publish, subscribe, etc. as anyone would expect.

However, I now need to use a wildcard, to subscribe like this:

```
a/b/+/c
```

The subscription is working fine.

So, if someone writes on, let's say, this topic:

```
a/b/12345/c
```

I am able to receive the message. To make it short, the funcionality is working fine.

However, I noticed that the MQTT-SN does the following (at low level):

1. ClientA sends SUBSCRIBE to topic `a/b/+/c`
2. MQTT-SN-Gateway answers with `SUBACK` message, and topic-id == 0 (following the specification)
3. On clientB, I publish on topic `a/b/123/c` which matches the wildcard in ClientA.
4. MQTT-SN-Gateway then sends a `REGISTER{topic-id=789,a/b/123/c}` message to ClientA.
5. ClientA then replies with `REGACK` to MQTT-SN-Gateway
6. MQTT-SN-Gateway then sends the data via `PUBLISH` with the `topic-id=789` to ClientA
7. ClientB sends again something on `a/b/123/c`
8. MQTT-SN-Gateway sends the data via `PUBLISH` with the `topic-id=789` to clientA

So, as you can see, at step 4, the Gateway assigns a topic-id to that topic ClientB published. So, on any new incoming messages, Gateway uses the topic-id rather than the string to represent the topic.

However, what I need for my particular case is to UNREGISTER from that topic as soon as I receive something. And, if I receive something again on that same topic, I would like to do the steps 4,5, and 6.

For this, I tried the following:

9. ClientA after receiving data, sends an `UNSUBSCRIBE{topic-id=789}`
10. MQTT-SN-Gateway answers with the `UNSUBACK`
11. ClientB sends some data on `a/b/123/c` again
12. MQTT-SN-Gateway then sends the payload via `PUBLISH` with the `topic-id=789` to clientA

Thus, the Gateway does not re-`REGISTER` again the topic with the ClientA (that is what I would expect).

Answer (score 0):

By checking the documentation [MQTT-SN 1.2 Spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/66091/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf) at section **7.3 Mapping of Topic Ids to Topic Names** the mapping is per client during a session.

So, my assumption that the MQTT-SN-Gateway would re-assign a topic-id for the same topic is wrong.

The correct behavior is that the client is the same, and the assignment of the topic-id was already done, the MQTT-SN-Gateway will keep the same topic-id as long as the client is connected.